# ASP.NET MVC3: What is the packages.config for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What is the asp.net MVC packages.config for?

Do I need items in there to reflect what's being used within the site/application?

Comment: No, I just installed MVC 3 and started a new project using the Razor View Engine.

Comment: huhu I made the century by giving +1 :P.. very nice question

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This file is managed by the NuGet infrastructure. It's used to track installed packages with their respective versions. If you installed the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update it uses NuGet by default to track packages such as jQuery, EntityFramework, Modernizr. That's why you might be seeing this file when you create a new bare bone project.

Comment: you are the best on StackOverflow for most of issues/challenges I face.

Answer (score 15):

To learn more about NuGet (and I highly recommend you do as it is one of the best things to be added to VS and C#/VB in years) look here:

[NuGet Frequently Asked Questions](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq)

[NetGet - Home](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Fortunately, it's not just a C# thing, works great for VB as well...  ;-)

Comment: @EdDeGagne Hopefully one day VB will no longer be a thing ;)

Comment: Yeah, been hearing that for almost 20 years now. If you don't use it, then why wish for it to no longer being "a thing"? Makes zero sense.